# Castle Windsor: Reuse resolved component in OnCreate, UsingFactoryMethod or DynamicParameters

Tags: castle-windsor, ioc-container

I'm trying to execute an action on a resolved component before it is returned as a dependency to the application.

For example, with this graph:

```
public class Foo : IFoo { }

public class Bar {
  IFoo _foo;
  IBaz _baz;
  public Bar(IFoo foo, IBaz baz) {
    _foo = foo;
    _baz = baz;
  }
}
```

When I create an instance of IFoo, I want the container to instantiate Bar and pass the already-resolved IFoo to it, along with any other dependencies it requires. So when I call:

```
var foo = container.Resolve<IFoo>();
```

The container should automatically call:

```
container.Resolve<Bar>(); // should pass foo and instantiate IBaz
```

I've tried using OnCreate, DynamicParameters and UsingFactoryMethod, but the problem they all share is that they don't hold an explicit reference to the component:
DynamicParameters is called before IFoo is instantiated.
OnCreate is called after, but the delegate doesn't pass the instance.
UsingFactoryMethod doesn't help because I need to register these components with TService and TComponent.

Ideally, I'd like a registration to look something like this:

```
container.Register<IFoo, Foo>((kernel, foo) => kernel.Resolve<Bar>(new { foo }));
```

Note that IFoo and Bar are registered with the transient life style, which means that the already-resolved instance has to be passed to Bar - it can't be "re-resolved".

Is this possible? Am I missing something?

Comment: IIRC OnCreate *does* pass the instance.

Comment: see http://github.com/castleproject/Castle.InversionOfControl/blob/master/src/Castle.Windsor.Tests/Lifecycle/OnCreateTestCase.cs

Comment: You're right. I'm not sure how I missed that. But I still can't resolve Bar automatically. Passing this 'container.Resolve<Bar>(new { foo = instance })' to OnCreate is creating a new instance of foo instead of using the resolved instance. I think this is happening because of the transient life style.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to resolve Bar when you're actually resolving IFoo. Either you want IFoo or you want Bar.

Comment: The application requests an IFoo: container.Resolve<IFoo>(). But the way it works is that a Bar has to be created to wrap, manage and initialize the IFoo instance before it's returned to the application. No objects will hold references to Bar: it will be GC'd as soon as the IFoo instance is disposed.

Comment: It seems you have a cyclic dependency: in order to resolve IFoo you need a Bar to initialize it, but Bar has a dependency on IFoo. You need to break the cyclic dependency.

Comment: Exactly. That's why I'm trying to pass the foo instance to Bar. Note the anonymous object in the first comment. I thought using that would circumvent resolving the IFoo dependency again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is what you want:

```
public interface IFoo {}
public class Foo : IFoo {}
public class Bar {
    public IFoo BarFoo { get; private set;}

    public Bar(IFoo foo) {
        BarFoo = foo;
    }

    public void DoSomething() {
        Console.WriteLine("Initializing");
    }
}

[Test]
public void Create() {
    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    var initialized = false;
    container.Register(Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<Foo>().LifeStyle.Transient
        .OnCreate((kernel, foo) => {
            var bar = kernel.Resolve<Bar>(new {foo});
            Assert.AreSame(foo, bar.BarFoo);
            bar.DoSomething();
            initialized = true;
        }));
    container.Register(Component.For<Bar>().LifeStyle.Transient);
    var f = container.Resolve<IFoo>();
    Assert.IsTrue(initialized);
}
```

It's actually almost a duplicate of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463895/circular-interfaces-dependencies-and-castle-windsor).

Comment: I've tried similar code. The expectation here is that passing the anonymous [new {foo}] would avoid creating resolving a new IFoo instance when resolving Bar, but my experience was different. The container kept creating new IFoo instances. Maybe I did something wrong. I'll try it again and let you know.

Comment: By the way, I'd seen the other question, but there are a couple of significant differences: 1. I don't need to hold an explicit reference to the Bar instance after IFoo is resolved. 2. Bar has a dependency on the transient IFoo and also on the global IBaz.

Comment: I've figure it out. Your code initially produced a cyclic dependency error. The problem was that I forgot to account for Windsor's property injection, as BarFoo (in real life) has a public setter. Once I added the OptionalPropertyInjectionFacility, your code worked.

Comment: @shovanik: the code works for me just as I posted it. The test passes.