# can castle resolve cross dependent properties?

Tags: c#, architecture, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

i have a situation silmilar as following

```
public class FooService : IFooService
{
    public IBarService BarService { get; set; }
}

public class BarService : IBarService
{
    public IFooService FooService { get; set; }
}
```

IFooService and IBarService both are inherited from IApplicationService
Component registrar looks like this

```
container.Register(
    AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<IApplicationService>()
        .BasedOn<IApplicationService>()
        .WithService.FromInterface()
        .LifestyleSingleton());
```

The problem is that properties are null. If i add any other service that doesnt use foo or bar service, the service is resolved correctlty.

It looks like castle windsor cant handle cross references. Or is there something i should add into component registrar?

Comment: Circular dependencies are a bad idea. You may want to revise your design. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2464211/246811

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried constructor injection and seems it is working.